# Child class calling unexpected overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading, template-meta-programming

I'm struggling to understand why in the following code the supposedly wrong overload is being called.

```
// overload.h
 struct T1
    {
      template<class... Args>
      void doFoo(Args&&... args)
        {
        std::cout << "T1 doFoo generic"<< std::endl;
        }

      void doFoo(int a)
        {
        std::cout << "T1 doFoo INT "<< std::endl;
        }

      void doFoo(double a)
        {
        std::cout << "T1 doFoo Double "<< std::endl;
        }

      template<class... Args>
      void foo(Args&&... args)
        {
        doFoo(args...);
        }
    };


  struct T2 : public T1
    {
      void doFoo(char c)
        {
        std::cout << "T2 doFoo char " << std::endl;
        }
    };

  // main.cpp

  #include <overload.h>
  int main()
    {
    T2 t2;
    t2.foo(3);
    t2.foo('A'); // This outputs: T1 doFoo generic 
    }
```

I was expecting that t2.foo('A') had as output: "T2 doFoo char", but instead I got "T1 doFoo generic".

If I move T2::doFoo(char c) into T1, everything works as expected. What's the reason of this behavior? any workaround?

Comment: Do you call `t2.foo('A');` or `t2.doFoo('A');`? I think if you would call `t2.doFoo('A');` you wold get the correct result.

Comment: yes, that's true. My intention is though to make all the doFoo functions protected, so that the only interface is foo(). So I need to call foo(myargs)

Comment: I see, but it looks like you expect that `T1::foo<...>` call the `doFoo` of a derived class, like a virtual function, but it will not work in that way - this is a static binding.

Comment: It's not exaclty like a virtual function call.  Statically, the compiler should be able to figure this overload out, as in this case it does not need runtime information. I am just looking for a way to make this happen without incurring in run-time overhead

Comment: Why do you expect `T1::foo` to call a function in the `T2` class?  `T1` doesn't know about `T2`.  When it calls `doFoo`, the type of `this` is `T1 *`.

Comment: Yes, I know. The only thing that could work is probably CRTP and injecting the child in the parent. However, logically, what I'm trying to express could make sense (maybe in other languages). Basically I just want to extend the overload in the child classes, you can consider this like a kind of virtual at compile time

Comment: I have tried using CRTP and it seems working.. the only thing is that I would have liked to avoid it. So still open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in comment, since `T1` doesn't know about the derived struct `T2`, `T1::foo` also can not find `T2::doFoo(char c)` and this static binding can not be achieved.

A simple workaround to spuriously overload `T1::foo` for `char` in `T2` would be again declaring `foo` in `T2` and overloading it as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/793SEaljgtuPlW7M)

```
struct T1 
{
    template<class... Args>
    void doFoo(Args&&... args){
        std::cout << "T1 doFoo generic"<< std::endl;
    }

    void doFoo(int a){
        std::cout << "T1 doFoo INT "<< std::endl;    
    }

    void doFoo(double a){
        std::cout << "T1 doFoo Double "<< std::endl;
    }

    template<class... Args>
    void foo(Args&&... args){
        doFoo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct T2 : public T1
{
    template<class... Args>
    void foo(Args&&... args){
        T1::foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void foo(char c){
        std::cout << "T2 foo char " << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Really interesting solution, probably it's what I was looking for. I'll try to test it, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Do you think this solution could be extendable, I mean, something like creating a struct TFinal that inherits from T1, T3, T4 etc and that has a method foo() that in some ways knows all the overloads?

Comment: @Saturnu Yes, this is definitely extendable like [**this**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2XhfK8K8EFYR3urd). But this also looks verbose :). Hmm.. I think that there may be a more simple solution.

Comment: interesting solution. Yep it seems extensible in that way, but it requires a fixed inheritance hierarchy while it could have been much better to have T2, T3, T4 etc and inherit only from the ones you need.. Difficult to achieve though

Comment: I think I have an idea, but it requires virtual inheritance and that introduces overhead. [Edit] there should not be overhead if I don't access to data members

Comment: @Saturnu Yes, my solution is applicable if and only if they has a fixed hierarchy `T1 <- T2 <- T3 <-...`. Do you want to extend the above static binding to the case of `struct TFinal : public T1, T3, T4`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that would be awesome

Comment: @Saturnu thx, I understand. Although It seems difficult for me at this point, it is an interesting question. Hmm...

Comment: no worries, your answer was more than good. The other would be the cherry on the cake eheh